# Rendering Zend_Form (white screen)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I create simple form in forms/user.php:

```
class Form_User extends Zend_Form
{
        public function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->setName('form_user');

        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');
        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');

        $this->addElements(array($username, $password, $email, $submit));
    }
}
```

My controller code is:

```
    public function registrationAction()
    {
        $this->view->title = 'Reg new acc!';
        $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');

        $form = new Form_User();
        $this->view->form = $form;

//     $this->view->form = 'test';
    }
```

and `<?php echo $this->form; ?>` 
When I render my form nothing happen, only white screen.
When I render with this code in controller  `$this->view->form = 'test';` it show me "Test" text. What to do?

Comment: maybe $form = new Application_Form_User() ? ;)

Comment: sorry, my mistake - without Application_...

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got `error_reporting` or `display_errors` turned off, so you won't see the fatal error when you try to instantiate `Form_User`, which should have been `Application_Form_User`.

Comment: errors are on in index file 
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

Comment: what are the settings in application.ini?  Bootstrapping can will overrule things you set in index.php

Comment: it's standart settings after creating new project